# What's the best value representation for boolean in DICOM?

Tags: dicom

AFAIK there's no boolean value representation, and I need to specify a boolean true/false in a private tag.

I thought of a `SH` (SHort string), saying `TRUE` or  `FALSE`. Is there a standard or widely used way to specify it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use a Coded String (CS) VR with `TRUE` and `FALSE` as coded values.
This is done in the standard for the `Time of Flight Information Used` element *(0018, 9755)* in the enhanced PET acquisition module.